# Is it normal practice to have intermediate type(s) just for data binding purposes? (WPF)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding

I have a collection of types that model a system. Now I want to show some functionality of this system in a GUI (WPF). But the relationship between the actual types isn't very databindable as is.

Is it normal practice to have intermediate type(s) just for data binding purposes?

Say something like:

```
public class EffectUIElement
{
    .Name <string>
    .Type <enum>
    .Usage <string>
}
```

where these values aren't in one place but several, so has to be pulled seperately.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is it normal practice to have intermediate type(s) just for data binding purposes?

Yes.  This is the "ViewModel" in MVVM (Model-View-ViewModel).  The MVVM pattern basically allows you to create a ViewModel that is used to expose the Model (your original data, which can come from one or more sources) to the View via Data Binding.

Comment: Thanks, btw is there a naming convention to use with these ViewModel types? Should I suffix them with View after the actual type being represented like EffectView?

Comment: @Joan: Most people tend to use "EffectView" for the XAML, and "EffectViewModel" for the VM.

Comment: @Joan: BTW - I wrote a fair amount describing this, especially for people who are coming from other backgrounds (ie: windows forms) at : http://reedcopsey.com/series/windows-forms-to-mvvm/

Comment: Thanks Reed, will check out your link now. Btw when you said EffectView for the XAML, you mean the name of the control itself, say TreeView? Because what if it's made up for many smaller controls?

Comment: @Joan: Typically, you'd have a UserControl that was intended to edit an "Effect" - it'd be an `EffectView`, with it's `DataContext` set to an instance of an `EffectViewModel`.  In this case, Effect == Model, EffectViewModel == ViewModel, and EffectView == View.  These could easily be composed inside of other user controls, pages, windows, etc - as needed.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's pretty normal. There is a pattern called [MVVM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) (Model-View-ViewModel), which is recommended by Microsoft for WPF development. In this pattern, what you describe is the "ViewModel".

Comment: Thanks, if what I described is ViewModel, then what's Model-View? Are they exclusive?

Comment: @Joan, Model and View are two different things (the pattern has three things, Model, View and ViewModel). View is the UI (basically your xaml) and Model is your implementation of whatever business problem your app solves. The ViewModel is a representation of your Model, decorated in a way that makes it suitable for display in your View.

Answer (score 2):

I do this quite often if data comes from different places, especially if it's from a database, I'll use an intermediate object to display data. I see nothing wrong with it, I think if you were hard pressed to stick to model classes, your code would be much more unreadable and the bindings were a mess.